# How to help/not hurt my half dead looking cactus?

Tags: cactus

I've had this cactus for a while and at some point I kinda forgot about it. Then suddenly I had the aspiration to save it so I began watering it once a month or so. The only problem is now I have a fully healthy and nicely growing top to a dead and decrepit bottom. I don't know exactly how to help it and I was just wondering if I should try to salvage the bottom or find a way to transplant the top.

Comment: Do you have a picture?

Comment: Welcome Eric! We really need to see your cactus, and get more details. How big/old is it? Do you know the variety? Is it all one type or is the top grafted to a different bottom? It's interesting that the top is getting better first. Have you changed anything else, like light or soil? Add anything you can think of right into your question by pressing [edit]. Check out our [help] to learn about our site. [Ask] is a good place to start. We look forward to helping you!

Comment: If the top is growing, the bottom isn't dead.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I would say the bottom isn't dead if the top is looking good and I think that the "dead" part is just going to take longer to look better and grow new parts.... I have a rose bush that almost died on my move from Washington State to Las Vegas and it still has a lot of dead looking parts but there is new healthy parts growing out of them so it has to be alive. But I know they aren't the same plants or anything but its just my opinion, I do have a good amount of knowledge of plants and flowers and trees but I don't know much about Cacti! I would google the cactus and the type that it is and the best care! But a good watering regularly and some plant food should help it a lot! Good Luck!